# RDP query, only require one session (console?)

Tags: windows, rdp

I have a VPS server running Windows Server 2008 and am slightly confused regarding RDP sessions.

I have set the server to automatically log onto the Administrator account and run programs from startup and as services. All good so far.

My problem is that if I try and then RDP into it, I get a new session and all the software tries to reload and then crashes. this has made me install VNC but obviously this is not as good as RDP.

My understanding, through searches, is that I need to restrict RDP sessions to the console session? Is this correct?

If yes, how do I achieve this? If no, how do I get round the problem I have?

I would also only want one session to be possible at any one time.

Essentially, I want RDP to act as the VNC is currently behaving.

I would be logging on from two different machines (not at the same time) one runs Win 7 and the other Win XP.

Thank you in advance for any help/suggestions.

Comment: Why running programs "from startup"? In a SERVER they should run - as a SERVICE.

Comment: Some run from startup (aminly my own scripts, software e,tc), most run as a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue that "REQUIRED" auto log on and a program to run at startup interactively.  The 3rd party didn't have a way to make it a service, and didn't really care to.

Same situation as well...it was a VPS, and I would have to RDP into it...which made the idea of "walking over to it" pointless and they didn't allow me access to VCenter.

Here's what I did:

1. Remove the automatic login
2. Remove the app from Startup
3. Purchase Firedaemon Pro (it's cheap...I think I spent under $30)
4. Install Firedaemon Pro on VPS server
5. Configure the app in FD Pro with `Interact with Desktop` checked and use whatever Logon account is necessary on that `Settings` page of the app service
6. Under "Dialogs" check the `Ignore Unknowns`

What this will do is create a service that will run when the VPS server boots and run that app in Session 0.  The great thing is you can simply RDP in when you need to check the app and open FD Pro and then right click on the Service and choose `Switch to Session0".  That will bring up the console desktop running the app.

For me this was more "secure" then simply leaving it as it was with auto logon and startup apps.  It also allows me to monitor if the "service" is running or not and send me alerts if it isn't.